# Triple countdown sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Let's start with the natural numbers

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100...
```

Now we will make a new list, replacing each natural number `n` with a countdown from `n` to `1`.

```
[1,2,1,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2,1,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6..
```

Now we will repeat the process.

```
[1,2,1,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,5,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,6,5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,6..
```

And now we will do it a third time:

```
[1,2,1,1,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,5,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,6,5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,5,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1...
```

This is the **triple countdown sequence**.

Your task is to implement the triple countdown sequence.  You may either take input and give the value of the sequence at that index, or you may simply output the terms starting from the beginning without stop.<sup>1</sup>

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being the goal.

---

<sup>1: Both zero and one indexing are permitted.  Outputting the terms without halt includes lazy structures which can produce an infinite number of terms.</sup>

Comment: The 0-indexed position of the first \$n\$ in the sequence is \$n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)/24\$, which is close to [A000332](https://oeis.org/A000332), only with a different indexing.

Comment: The 0-indexed position of the second \$n\$ in the sequence is [A145126](https://oeis.org/A145126).

Comment: Another interesting question would be the n-th countdown sequence.

Comment: @ykcul not so interesting I suppose, the trivial solution will be to just replace loop 3 times with n times

Comment: @wasif I meant take in n and output the nth countdown sequence.

Comment: @Arnauld The first appearance of each number is the cumulative sums of [A000292](https://oeis.org/A000292)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)!
-1 byte thanks to [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)!

```hs
[1..]>>=f>>=f>>=f
f x=[x,x-1..1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfbhvzP9pQTy/Wzs42DYa50hQqbKMrdCp0gTKGsf9zEzPzbAuKMvNKFNL//0tOy0lML/6vm1xQAAA)

Comment: You can save 1 byte with [do notation](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h0DYlX6HCRrfQOrpCp0LXUE/PMJYr3TZNBQijgbzY/7mJmXkKtgoFRZl5JQrp/wE "Haskell – Try It Online").

Comment: Simpler and a byte shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfbhvzP9pQTy/Wzs42DYa50hQqbKMrdCp0gTKGsf9zEzPzbAuKMvNKFNL//0tOy0lML/6vm1xQAAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
∞3FLí˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8Yzefw2tPz/n/HwA)

Infinitely outputs, thanks to Kevin Crujisen

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
L3FLí˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx9jN5/Da03P@/zc0AAA)

I doubt it could be beaten

Comment: I don't think you can output the terms in this way..."You may either take input and give the value of the sequence at that index, or you may simply output the terms starting from the beginning without stop"

Comment: @ZaMoC Luckily that can easily be fixed by [changing the leading `L` to `∞` to output an infinite list](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8Yzefw2tPz/n/HwA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks!!

Comment: @ZaMoC fixed !!

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 12 bytes

Returns the *n*th number in the series.

```apl
⊢⊃1(∊…¨⍨)⍣3⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HXokddzYYajzq6HjUsO7TiUe8KzUe9i40f9W7@n/aobcKj3j6g/KPeNY96txxab/yobeKjvqnBQc5AMsTDM/h/moIhV5qCERAbA7EJEJsCsRkQmwOxBRBbArGhAQA)

`⊢` the argument

`⊃` picks the element from

`1(`…`)⍣3⍳` repeat thrice with 1 as constant left argument and **i**ndices 1 through *n* as initial right argument:

`∊` **e**nlist (flatten)

`…` the sequence

`¨` for each

`⍨` with swapped arguments, i.e. counting down from that number to 1

Answer (score 5):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 50 bytes

```
def f:[range(.)+1]|reverse[];
1|while(1;.+1)|f|f|f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNU0hzSq6KDEvPVVDT1PbMLamKLUstag4NTrWmsuwpjwjMydVw9BaT9tQsyYNBP///5dfUJKZn1f8XzcPAA)

funny how similar the second line is to the Zsh answer.

-1 from ovs.

Comment: Infinite output fixes this while being a byte shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNU0hzSq6KDEvPVVDT1PbMLamKLUstag4NTrWmsuwpjwjMydVw9BaT9tQsyYNBP///5dfUJKZn1f8XzcPAA "jq – Try It Online") Using `range(.;0;-1)` is a bit shorter than `range`+`reverse` as well and the newline is not necessary

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 37 bytes

```
c()xargs -i seq {} -1 1
seq inf|c|c|c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwcLqpaUlaboWN1WTNTQrEovSixV0MxWKUwsVqmsVdA0VDLlA7My8tJpkEIQoXlVbk5GamKKgq2IIEVgabWhgELsAwgEA)

Full program which outputs infinitely, one per line  (ATO link includes a wrapper to halt after N terms).

"Implicit" "list" "flattening" FTW! (Zsh doesn't actually have any of these features - it's just text!)

`c` is a function that outputs the `seq`uence from `{}` to `1` (with a step of `-1`) for each `{}` in the input (`xargs -i`). Then output "all" integers and pipe that to `c` three times.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 60 bytes

```javascript
for(a=1;;a++)for(i=a;--i;)for(j=i;--j;)for(k=j;--k;)print(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcfBCoAwCADQ35kMD90C8WMkCFRow8Z@31a92zOZch@hfeDcM88WRXgjklrhjbIQotIXY12xP8624gQ99BrFIfMB)

Boring trivial solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
!4¡ṁṫN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X9Hk0MKHOxsf7lzt9/8/AA)

outputs an infinite list.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 36 bytes

```
Do[Print[0;],{,∞},#,#,#]&@{,,1,-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98lPzqgKDOvJNrAOlanWudRx7xaHWUQjFVzqNbRMdTRNaz9/x8A)

Prints elements indefinitely.

---

A somewhat more interesting solution which generalizes to \$n\$-countdown sequences:

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 48 bytes

```
Nest[gArray[g,#,{#,1}]&,Print,3]@i~Do~{i,∞}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98vtbgkOv39pIWORUWJldHpOso61co6hrWxajoBRZl5JTrGsQ6ZdS75ddWZOo865tX@/w8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 33 bytes

Outputs terms without stopping!

```powershell
filter s{$_..1}
for(){++$x|s|s|s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f8/LTOnJLVIobhaJV5Pz7CWKy2/SMNapUI3J9VUs1pbW6WiphgEa/9z/QcA) *Note: the linked TIO limits the output*

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
r1)⁺⁺Fị@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/IUPNR4y4gcnu4u9vh/@H2R01r/v83MgAA)

Because it is extremely cumbersome to produce infinite output in Jelly, it instead applies countdown 3 times to the input's range and outputs the input-th item. The part without indexing (6 bytes) ties with [05AB1E's equivalent](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235530/78410).

```
r1)⁺⁺Fị@    Monadic main link. Input = n
r1)         [x,x-1..1] for each number x (autorange)
   ⁺⁺       Do the above; do the above (no autorange)
     Fị@    Flatten and get the nth item
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 60 bytes

```scala
Stream.from(1)flatMap>flatMap>flatMap>
def> =(_:Int)to(1,-1)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jfpbO2ekQre7BbIOSmxdGg)

<s>A less trivial solution should be coming soon.</s>

`>` is a function that takes an `Int` and returns a range going from that number to 1. We then take an infinite `Stream` starting at 1, and apply `>` to each of those numbers thrice, flattening each time.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 45 bytes

```
Flatten[r@r@r@Range@#][[#]]&
r=Range[#,1,-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773y0nsaQkNS@6yAEEgxLz0lMdlGOjo5VjY9W4imzBAtHKOoY6uoaxav8DijLzShT0HdL1oUrNDP7/BwA)

-23 bytes from @att

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773y0nsaQkNS@6yAEEgxLz0lMdlGOjo5VjY9W4imzBAtHKOoY6uoaxav8DijLzShT0HdL1oUrNDP7/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 33 bytes

```
(1..*,{.flatmap:{$_...1}}...*)[3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1up4JCoYPtfw1BPT0unWi8tJ7EkN7HAqlolXk9Pz7C2FkhqaUYbx/63VihOBCmOjjM0MIj9DwA)

This is a lazy list of countdown sequences, where the first element is the list of natural numbers, the second is the countdown sequence, the third is the double countdown sequence, and the fourth is the triple countdown sequence, et cetera.  The triple countdown sequence is the one at index `3`, which is returned.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> 51 bytes

```r
`[`=`for`;while(F<-F+1)i[F:1,j[i:1,k[j:1,show(k)]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyE6wTYhLb8owbo8IzMnVcPNRtdN21AzM9rNylAnKzoTSGZHZwHJ4oz8co1szdjY2P//AQ)

Prints the resulting sequence infinitely.

---

Less boring:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 68 bytes

```r
`!`=unlist;s=sapply;while(F<-F+1)cat(!s(!s(F:1,seq,,-1),seq,,-1),"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0ExwbY0LyezuMS62LY4saAgp9K6PCMzJ1XDzUbXTdtQMzmxREOxGITcrAx1ilMLdXR0DTURDCUlzf//AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 101 bytes

```cpp
#include<cstdio>
int a,x,y,z;main(){for(;;)for(x=a++;x--;)for(y=x;y--;)for(z=y;z;)printf("%d,",z--);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJrm4JCUz344rM69EIVGnQqdSp8o6NzEzT0OzOi2/SMPaWhNEVdgmamtbV@jqQriVthXWlTBOlW2ldZW1ZkER0Ig0DSXVFB0lnSpdXU3r2v//AQ)

Comment: [94 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcxBCoAgEEDRq4QQKM6cYPAsYoYhlIkYqNHZrYhWn7f5NkZcrO3dhzwYKFCh0WZ84OJ0e@JE4k1RRkoqiB@rKlR/NFWpkdB6OvyafdAxPTPH2TgDg4Yo6Or9Bg "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 69 bytes

Nested Ternary operator solution.

`a`, `b` and `c` are the triple countdown state from fastest to slowest, and `d` is the increasing count. `a` is printed for every step in the countdown. (make that a+1 thanks to AZTECCO

Thanks to AZTECCO for -10 bytes!! And -2 more!!!
It took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out what's going on with the last suggestion, that's some serious golfing.

```c
a,b,c,d;main(){for(;;a=!a?b=!b?c-=c?1:--d:b-1:a-1)printf("%d,",a+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoAgDADQb1EIlLbDrg7xW@bE8JCFdIu@fb2neKiaCVRQaHzKmCG@/VqBWbKTUrOrRTFroYTYUkVKghTvNebTg98aeJCdIn9mPw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `combinators.extras lists lists.lazy`, 58 bytes

```
[ 1 lfrom [ [ 1 [a,b] >list ] lmap-lazy lconcat ] thrice ]
```

Running in the listener, as `lmap-lazy` postdates build 1525, the one TIO uses. Note that output has been limited to 30 so I could actually take the screenshot. This limitation is not present in the code itself.

[image]

### Explanation

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that returns an infinite lazy list of the triple countdown sequence.

- `1 lfrom` An infinite lazy list of the natural numbers.
- `[ ... ] thrice` Apply a quotation (to the natural numbers) three times.
- `[ ... ] lmap-lazy` Use a quotation to map over a lazy list.
- `1 [a,b] >list` Create a list from an input number to one. e.g. `5` -> `L{ 5 4 3 2 1 }`
- `lconcat` Concatenate a list of lists into a single list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift](https://swift.org/), 103 bytes

```swift
let a:([Int])->[Int]={$0.flatMap{(1...$0).reversed()}};(1...).forEach{a(a(a([$0]))).forEach{print($0)}}
```

Functional programming in Swift, excepting the `print` call, which obviously is non-pure.

`a` is a closure that converts an array of integers to an array of their countdown, which is called three times for every number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/J7VEIdFKI9ozryRWU9cOTNtWqxjopeUklvgmFlRrGOrp6akYaOoVpZalFhWnpmho1tZag0U19dLyi1wTkzOqEzVAMFrFIFZTEyFaUJSZV6IB1Ftb@/8/AA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm not sure about swift but on TIO your output looks a little strange.  It seems like you gave it `5` as input and it output several terms and then stopped.

Comment: @WheatWizard the code prints the triple countdown sequence for the first 5 natural numbers. Maybe I misunderstood the first half of the requirements `You may either take input and give the value of the sequence at that index`?

Comment: @WheatWizard fixed the code, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles), 6 bytes

```
<$/, 3,~.@\,
```

explanation

```
<$      # first int input elements
  /     # fold
   ,3   # [1,2,3] (any list of length 3 would work)
   ,~   # [1,2,...inf] (initial value to fold)
   .@   # map on accumulator
     \, # reverse of list from 1 to
        # implicit $ (the element of list to map)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
def c(x,i):i>0<x!=(print(x),c(x-1,i),c(x-1,i-1))
i=1
while 1:c(i,2);i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFZo0InU9Mq087ApkLRVqOgKDOvRKNCUwcormsIlIExdA01NbkybQ25yjMyc1IVDK2SNTJ1jDStM7VtDf//BwA)

-19 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard by using even more recursion
-1 byte thanks to ovs

Comment: @WheatWizard Oh that `i*x` trick is very nice. And yes, that's a very nice save, thanks.

Comment: You can save another byte with chained comparison instead of the `if` statement: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFZo0InU9Mq087ApkLRVqOgKDOvRKNCUwcormsIlIExdA01NbkybQ25yjMyc1IVDK2SNTJ1jDStM7VtDf//BwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: The output of the 73 byte version doesn't match the challenge; There is a 1 missing right at the start. The original program was fine

Comment: @ovs It looks fine to me? Anyway, thanks for the byte save

Comment: @hyper-neutrino yours starts *1 2 1 1 3* instead of *1 2 1 1 **1** 3*

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 51 bytes

```javascript
e=f=>i=>{for(;--i;)f(i)};e(_=>e(e(e(print)))(-_))``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcIxCoAwDAXQ6@QP2YWSXqUtkkActNTSRTx7RN472mr3PrxPXluEikl2yY9dgxKzJxg53qRUJCv9@vBzAiAuQK0RHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
)╒3æ╒mx─§
```

Outputs the 0-based value.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/z0dRJxoeXAcncikdTGg4t///fgMuQy4jLmMuEyxDINOUyNwAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
)          # Increase the (implicit) input-integer by 1 (work-around for input 0)
 ╒         # Pop and push a list in the range [1,input+1]
  3æ       # Loop 3 times, using four characters as inner code-block:
    ╒      #  Convert each integer in the list to a [1,n] ranged list
     m     #  Map over each list:
      x    #   Reverse the list
       ─   #  Flatten the list of lists
        §  # After the loop, get the value at the (implicit) input as index
           # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>132</s> <s>123</s> <s>114</s> <s>113</s> 112 bytes

```cpp
#include<argp.h>
main(int a,int b){if(a<2)for(;;)main(2,a++);while(--b)if(a<4)main(a+1,b);else printf("%d,",b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJrEovUAvw44rNzEzTyMzr0QhUQdEJmlWZ6ZpJNoYaablF2lYW2uC5Y10ErW1Na3LMzJzUjV0dZM0wWpMIJKJ2oY6SZrWqTnFqQoFRUBD0jSUVFN0lECCtf//AwA)

Thanks to @wheat-wizard for tip on removing all whitespace

Comment: [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcxNCoAgEEDhq0QQzKAuilYZdBQZLWugTKJoEZ3dfjZv88FzMarRuZQW4gAc9ozkV4sXe6C2Qr9uoDX@XkkSAvU58TyAUhaprbtfSJTSYmOMPXjeOZi4vRsPedHL/BV9p/QA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 56 bytes

```julia
~i=i:-1:1
!i=[.~i...;]
for i=1:-1%UInt println.(!!!i)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7TNtNK19DKkEsx0zZary5TT0/POpYrLb9IIdPWECijGuqZV6JQUJSZV5KTp6ehqKiYqZmal/L/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

There's gotta be a better way than this.

Outputs the `n`th term, 0-indexed.

```
gÈc!õ1}g3NËôÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Z8hjIfUxfWczTsv0xA&input=MjU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 48 bytes

```perl
sub d{sub c{map{reverse 1..$_}@_}sub{c c c++$i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhpRpEJlfnJhZUF6WWpRYVpyoY6umpxNc6xNcCpaqTFYBQW1sls7b2f0FRZl6JBlCpQrWSSryOUq1Ciq6dhqamQnlGZg5Q338A)

Returns an anonymous sub that can be called repeatedly to obtain the next list of items in the sequence. Ungolfed and commented:

```perl
sub d {
    sub c {
        # This is where the magic happens. c(1) returns (1), c(2) returns (2, 1).
        # c(1, 2, 3) returns (1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1)
        return map {reverse 1 .. $_} @_;
    }
    # 3 nested calls to c() to get the triple countdown
    return sub{c(c(c(++$i)))};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```ruby
x=0
loop{x-=1;eval"(x...0).map{|x|"*3+"p -x}}}"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8LWgCsnP7@gukLX1tA6tSwxR0mjQk9Pz0BTLzexoLqmokZJy1hbqUBBt6K2tlap9v9/AA)

- outputs infinitely

We eval "(x...0).map{|x|"*3 which becomes a depth 3 loop

x is decremented thus negative so that we can use range x..0

Then we put -x

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ɾṘ3(vɾf)Ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BE%E1%B9%983%28v%C9%BEf%29%E1%B9%98&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⁰ηＷ›θＬυ«≦⊖ηＦ…η⁰Ｆ…κ⁰Ｆ…λ⁰⊞υμ»Ｉ±§υ⊖θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NCsIwEITP7VPkuIEI9eKlp6IghVqKbxDbNSmmac2PCuKzx5R6KLi3GeabnVZy045chVDqybvaDxc0cKd5WljbCw0ZIzKqp@wVEjga5G4OMFKhFk6Cp5SSd5qc@PQjDtgaHFA77BY2uY6GwJlrgSAZySKwcm5/jlqcxttYz8gQKz5pY3rtYM@tgxpFHAGFK3WHrzmyehm3z5eHsN2FzUN9AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the 1-indexed `n`th value. Explanation: Based on @AZTECCO's answer, generates the triple countup sequence for the negated natural numbers, and then negates the final value to produce the desired result.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔⁰η
```

Start with no terms.

```
Ｗ›θＬυ«
```

Repeat until we have at least `n` terms.

```
≦⊖η
```

Get the next negated natural number.

```
Ｆ…η⁰Ｆ…κ⁰Ｆ…λ⁰⊞υμ
```

Generate the triple countup for that number.

```
»Ｉ±§υ⊖θ
```

Output the `n`th term, negating to give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 14 bytes

```
r1{m{ro^p}}3E!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/yLA6t7ooP66gttbYVfH/fwA)

```
r1    # Range 1..inf
{
 m{   # Apply to each
  ro  # Range from 1..N
  ^p  # Push in reverse
 }
}
3E!   # Run 3 times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```rust
|i|{let g=|n|(1..=n).rev();(1..).flat_map(g).flat_map(g).flat_map(g).nth(i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcpBCoMwEIXhtZ4idTUDZUBBN5KzlCyMBuIg6VgXSc6e1mWhdfc/vhf2pxTLajWOAVWsKz@Jsrokl@KZs06coCXSjBSmF@B4LiTrjTxWs8H8v1kWcJjLWFdbcCyeb9DE3NwttEg7H@HzQ/zB3TX31zx8cS5v)

*-1 bytes thanks to `..=n` trick*

Takes `i` as a `usize`, returns the `ith` item in the sequence.
Conveniently returns it as an `Option<i32>` monad, so if you somehow pass an `i` greater than the length of the sequence (impossible because it's an infinite sequence), it will return `None`.
[Relevant meta ruling on returning monads](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14275/44998)

See below for explanation of how it generates the sequence.

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>94</s> <s>90</s> 89 bytes

```rust
let g=|n|(1..=n).rev();for i in(1..).flat_map(g).flat_map(g).flat_map(g){print!("{} ",i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUP0/J7VEId22Jq9Gw1BPzzZPU68otUxD0zotv0ghUwGoBiiqqZeWk1gSn5tYoJGOk11dUJSZV6KooVRdq6Ckk6lZ@7/2PwA)

*-4 bytes cos why was this a closure?*
*-1 bytes thanks to `..=n` trick*

Rust iterators are very fun.
Prints the entire sequence.

`(1..)` creates an infinite range starting at 1.
`flat_map(g)` is equivalent to `map(g).flatten()`.
`g` in this case generates a range from `n` to `1` inclusive. Rust ranges are strictly ascending, so we have to do `(1..=n).rev()`.
`=n` is used to tell Rust that the max here is inclusive, as it's a byte shorter than `n+1`.
I do wish there were a shorter way to call `flat_map(g)` three times without literally calling it three times...

Answer (score 1):

## Math++, 64 bytes

```
a+1>a
a>b
b>c
c>d
d
d-1>d
5+3*!d>$
c-1>c
4+6*!c>$
b-1>b
3-2*!b>$
```